# Searching through Stackoverflow.com from the commandline/bash

Tags: command-line

As the title says i am looking for a way to search through stackoverflow.com using only the command line specifically bash in linux.

Things I need to accomplish :

> I just need to get the top 10 answers for my question or even top 5.
>
> Plain Text Output , i.e. strip
>       HTML out if possible.

Also I would prefer if you didnt give a answer that required elinks or something similar.

Comment: My answer, before I read your last sentence, was "Lynx, Links, w3m, cURL, ... and a bit basic knowledge about HTTP and string modification in Bash."

Comment: Yeah i thought of that as well , i was hoping there was some kind of API , since i am not sure if they would like us scraping the site

Comment: However, this question more belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

here's a rough script to run from command line that does the job

```
wget 'http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=command-line&sort=newest' -qO - | perl -nle ' print $1 if /\<title[^>]+\>([^<]*)/;'|head
```

It grabs RSS output for a given tag (*command-line* here) and sort of parses it.
To be done properly one would probably want to parse XML in a better way or use some perl rss parser.